# Is it possible for a npm package to accept parameters

Tags: node.js, npm

Is it  possible to create an npm package which accepts parameters?
e.g.

`npm install mypackage --save -**meaningOfLife:42**`

Thanks

Comment: What behavior are you expecting by passing other options?